# Tomorrow: rainy with a chance of null objects

Tags: java, object-oriented, stream, null, community-challenge

In an attempt to hide from the sun outside, I gave the [community challenge "Rainfall"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6911/97584) a try.

Code here, specific questions below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RainfallChallenge
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // building the farm
        int size = input.nextInt();
        Farm farm = new Farm(size);

        // setting heights, creating fields
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                farm.putField(x, y, new Field(input.nextInt()));

        // skynet addon: knows every field as key and maps to the list of all fields of its basin
        HashMap<Field, ArrayList<Field>> basins = new HashMap<Field, ArrayList<Field>>();

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                groupFields(basins, farm.getField(x, y));

        // from lists of fields to sorted list of basin sizes
        System.out.println(
            new StringBuilder(
                basins.values()
                .stream()
                .distinct()                                     // set of field lists
                .mapToInt(b -> b.size())                        // to their number of fields
                .sorted()                                       
                .boxed()                                        // in bubble wrap
                .map(String::valueOf)                           // to String stream
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))).reverse());  // desired order
    }

    private static ArrayList<Field> groupFields(HashMap<Field, ArrayList<Field>> basins, Field field)
    {
        ArrayList<Field> basin;

        // end recursion: revisit field
        if(basins.containsKey(field)) 
        {
            return basins.get(field);
        }
        // end recursion: new basin
        else if(field.getLowestNeighbor() == field) 
        {
            basin = new ArrayList<Field>();
        }
        // recursion: find basin of lowest neighbor
        else
        {
            basin = groupFields(basins, field.getLowestNeighbor());
        }

        basin.add(field);
        basins.put(field, basin);
        return basin;
    }
}

class Farm
{
    private Field[][] fields;

    public Farm(int size)
    {
        fields = new Field[size][size];
    }

    public void putField(int x, int y, Field field)
    {
        fields[x][y] = field;

        // check all 4 neighbors
        field.setNeighbor(getField(x + 1, y));
        field.setNeighbor(getField(x - 1, y));
        field.setNeighbor(getField(x, y + 1));
        field.setNeighbor(getField(x, y - 1));
    }

    public Field getField(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            return fields[x][y] != null ? fields[x][y] : NullField.instance;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            return NullField.instance;
        }
    }
}

class Field
{
    private int height;
    private Field lowestNeighbor;

    public Field(int height)
    {
        this.height = height;
        lowestNeighbor = this;
    }

    public void setNeighbor(Field neighbor)
    {
        if (neighbor.height < lowestNeighbor.height)
        {
            lowestNeighbor = neighbor;
        }
        else if (neighbor.lowestNeighbor.height > height)
        {
            neighbor.lowestNeighbor = this; 
        }
    }

    public Field getLowestNeighbor()
    {
        return lowestNeighbor;
    }
}

class NullField extends Field
{
    public static final NullField instance = new NullField();

    private NullField()
    {
        super(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

I got lazy and put everything into one file. General reviews are appreciated, as always.

However, there are two things I want to specifically ask about:

1. I'm new to **`Stream`**.

   ```
   // from lists of fields to sorted list of basin sizes
   System.out.println(
       new StringBuilder(
           basins.values()
           .stream()
           .distinct()                                     // set of field lists
           .mapToInt(b -> b.size())                        // to their number of fields
           .sorted()                                       
           .boxed()                                        // in bubble wrap
           .map(String::valueOf)                           // to String stream
           .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))).reverse());  // desired order
   ```

   I think this code does quite a lot (values of a `HashMap` as a `Set`, to integers, sorted, to `String`) in a compact yet readable way and I see the value of this language feature. Is there anything bad? I had to use `StringBuilder` to reverse the result. This seems bad. The `Stream` cannot be reversed as it's considered endless in general. There are [workarounds for when I know it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order), but they aren't very readable and not self documenting at all. Ideally, I want to tell `.sorted()` if I want the order to be ascending or descending. But there's no parameter for that. How can this be done more elegantly?
2. The use of "**null object**" pattern to build the grid. The problem I'm trying to solve here is that not every `Field` has all 4 neighbors. The first one at (0/0) has none at (-1/0) and (0/-1). Also, during construction, future fields are not yet available. The idea behind the pattern (as far as I understand it) is to always have an object, no matter what. If the logic of the program does not allow it, return a special object that acts "neutrally" in the calculation of the program.

   ```
   public Field getField(int x, int y)
   {
       try
       {
           return fields[x][y] != null ? fields[x][y] : NullField.instance;
       }
       catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
       {
           return NullField.instance;
       }
   }
   ```

   This way, there's always an object returned by `getField` and never `null`. Does it make sense to apply this pattern here? I only heard of use cases where it might substitute a an uninitialised Object to prevent checks for `null` in the actual code. I thought the fields out of bounds or not yet created are good examples for that. Is the implementation with exceptions ok? This will occur quite often during execution.

   ```
   class NullField extends Field
   {
       public static final NullField instance = new NullField();

       private NullField()
       {
           super(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
       }
   }
   ```

   I made this a singleton because I only want to create one such object. There's no second `null` either. Other than that I could have provided `@Override`s for the methods of the `Field` class, for example:

   ```
   public void setNeighbor(Field neighbor)
   {
       // pffft, whatever
   }
   ```

   But I never call those on the nullobject, so I omitted them. Is this bad practise?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the stream using a `Comparator` using `sorted(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`

You want to sort using the reverse of the natural order, there is a static method in `Compartator` to get the Comparator you need.

```
.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

You could make some small changes in your stream code to use this method:

```
System.out.println( 
    basins.values()
    .stream()
    .distinct()                                // set of field lists
    .map(b -> b.size())                        // to their number of fields
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder)           // desired order                            
    .map(Integer::toString)                    // to String stream
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Comment: Great tip. I didn't know this is possible. Why is this not part of the [`sorted()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sorted)? To make this work with the original code, the order of boxing and sorting has to be reversed: first box, then sort.

Comment: `Stream` has a method [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) with a `Comparator` parameter but `IntStream` doesn't have this method. You are using `mapToInt` and then `boxed` after sorting. I would change `mapToInt` to `map` and remove `boxed`. This way you can use the `sort`method in `Stream` and your code is boxing the sizes to Integer in both cases.

Comment: Ah, this is where auto boxing happens. The new code reduces self documentation a little bit as it's not mapping to int explicitly, but due to the shortness of the code and the call to `size()` this is an ok price I'm willing to pay to get rid of the explicit boxing line. Thanks.